# Problems understanding and using double pointers

Tags: c++, directshow

I am not sure how to use double pointers.

The function i need to use looks as following:

```
HRESULT GetBuffer(
  [out]  IMediaSample **ppBuffer,
  [in]   REFERENCE_TIME *pStartTime,
  [in]   REFERENCE_TIME *pEndTime,
  [in]   DWORD dwFlags
);
```

Documentation says:

> ppBuffer [out]
>
> Receives a pointer to the buffer's IMediaSample interface. The caller must release the interface.

This is what i tried using it:

```
HRESULT MCMyOutputPin::Deliver(IMediaSample* sample)
{
    HRESULT hr = NO_ERROR;
    myLogger->LogDebug("In Outputpin Deliver", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
    if (sample->GetActualDataLength() > 0)
    {
        IMediaSample **outsample;



        m_pAllocator->GetBuffer(outsample, NULL, NULL, NULL); //Access violation here
        BYTE** sampleBuffer;
        BYTE** newBuffer;
        sample->GetPointer(sampleBuffer);

        (*outsample)->GetPointer(newBuffer);

        memcpy((void *)newBuffer, (void *)sampleBuffer, sizeof(**sampleBuffer));

        m_pInputPin->Receive(*outsample);

        sample->AddRef();
    }

    return hr;
    //Forward to filter
}
```

Which gives me an:

> Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Then i tried using the address operator:

```
hr = m_pAllocator->GetBuffer(&outsample, NULL, NULL, NULL); //outsample is set to NULL
    BYTE* sampleBuffer = NULL;
    BYTE*  newBuffer = NULL;
    sample->GetPointer(&sampleBuffer);

    outsample->GetPointer(&newBuffer);

    memcpy((void *)newBuffer, (void *)sampleBuffer, sizeof(*sampleBuffer));

    m_pInputPin->Receive(outsample);
```

This sets outsample to NULL.

So what is the correct syntax to handle double pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first, high-level comment, is that you are not checking the return values of the functions that you call. It's a mistake to neglect error checking. Your first step is to add the necessary error checking.

---

```
HRESULT GetBuffer(
  [out]  IMediaSample **ppBuffer,
  [in]   REFERENCE_TIME *pStartTime,
  [in]   REFERENCE_TIME *pEndTime,
  [in]   DWORD dwFlags
);
```

The first parameter is used to return a `IMediaSample*` to the caller. You need to declare a variable of type `IMediaSample*`, and pass its address:

```
IMediaSample* sample;
....
hr = m_pAllocator->GetBuffer(&outsample, ...);
// check hr
....
```

So, `outsample` is of type `IMediaSample*`. When you take its address, with `&outsample`, you now have something of type `IMediaSample**`, which is what you need.

Remember that when working with interfaces, you always work with a pointer to the interface.

---

You've made the same mistake with the `BYTE**` parameters. Again, declare variables of type `BYTE*`, and pass the address of these variables to the functions that you call.

```
BYTE* sampleBuffer;
BYTE* newBuffer;
....
hr = sample->GetPointer(&sampleBuffer);
// check hr
hr = outsample->GetPointer(newBuffer);
// check hr
```

---

Using `sizeof(**sampleBuffer)` in your call to `memcpy` is wrong. In your code, where `sampleBuffer` is wrongly declared as `BYTE**`, `sizeof(**sampleBuffer)` is just `sizeof(BYTE)` which is always 1.

In fact you can conclude that any use of `sizeof` is incorrect here because `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time. You need to find the actual size of the dynamic buffer at runtime using whatever functionality these interfaces provide.

---

The call to `sample->AddRef()` looks a little suspect. I don't see any evidence that anything has taken a new reference to the interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
    IMediaSample **outsample;

    m_pAllocator->GetBuffer(outsample, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

You're passing the function the *value* of `outsample`, which is a garbage value since it doesn't point to anything. You want:

```
    IMediaSample *outsample;

    m_pAllocator->GetBuffer(&outsample, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This gives the function the address of `outsample` so that it can stuff the pointer it wants to return in it.

Answer (score 0):

I try to simulate the function as test, which using int** as output . the problem here is the function is suppose *output is is valid, so in the first way ,you have to make sure that, you might want to do something as this

```
 sample = new IMediaSample[1]
```

this is my sample code, hope it helps

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(int** output ,int* in)
{
    *output = new int[1];
    output[0][0] = in[0];
}
int main()
{
   int a[]  ={ 2 }; 
   int* out1;
   test(&out1 ,a);
   cout << out1[0] << endl; 
   int** out2;
   out2 = new int*[1];
   test(out2 ,a);
   cout << out2[0][0] << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really really don't want to do this: `sample = new IMediaSample[1];`